# Balabolka options don't save and reset to default every run

Tags: windows-10, balabolka

I have to set my preferences in Balabolka in "Options -> Settings" anew every time I reopen this program.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? How did you solve it?

I use windows 10. My user has admin rights.

```
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 20H2
OS build    19042.804
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having same issues when removing unused themes from portable edition.

---

0. In Balabolka installation folder there should be `balabolka.pcfg` file. If You don't see it - enable hidden files in Windows explorer options.
1. Make its backup. (copy it somewhere)
2. Edit Balabolka settings now.
3. Open `balabolka.pcfg` file in any text editor i.e. Notepad.
4. Open **BACKUPED** `balabolka.pcfg` in any text editor.

   4.1 Select all file content.

   4.2 Copy all file content.

   4.3 Close the file.
5. Return to **ORIGINAL** `balabolka.pcfg` file

   5.1. Select all file content.

   5.2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

   5.3. Close the file.

---

From now on settings should be saved. I recommend doing all configuration in one session, since You will have to repeat each steps if You will decide to configure something.